# Memory efficiency: Object vs struct

Tags: c#, memory

Just a quick background on the problem. I'm developing an application on a smart card with a reduced .net framework and very limited resources (16Kb of ram). I designed and developed a solution using object orientation but this solution uses a lot of memory. Went back and refactored the code to reduce memory consumption where possible but still it used to much memory.

Now I'm using a procedural approach and using struct to encapsulate data. I'm having success with this approach.

This may sound silly because the struct solution is working. Now the question is: is this the best solution for resource constraint devices or was there my object orientated solution poorly designed? Then another thing how can I reduce the exe size? Not sure what impacts the exe size?

Thanks

Comment: structure is value type, so storage is allocated in `stack`, where as object is reference type so allocate the memory in `heap`

Comment: Your question provides zero relevant details and is impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: Pointless to ask for comments on code we cannot see

Comment: The title clearly asks: Does a class use more or less memory than a struct.

Comment: @un-lucky: That's an oversimplification which is unhelpful in my experience.

Comment: @john Skeet : That means storage, whether it is in stack or it  is in heap doesn't affect the memory conception na?

Comment: @un-lucky your original comment is factually wrong. Structs may be allocated on the heap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well...that's a bit broad without some context. :-)  If a struct is boxed, it'll be on the heap. If it's a member of a class, it'll be boxed up and stored on the heap, etc. Is it safe to assume that what you're really saying is that there's no iron-clad guarantee that just because you make it a struct, that it will end up only allocated on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed code is resource hungry. With that limited resources, you should use C++ with as little C++/CLI, MFC, and .NET as possible. Performance is better too...

Of course DES encryption could exist on that size executable. It's not that difficult; I analyzed how to break DES 10 years ago in college. You just need to mean and lean executables...

I do not think there is a huge additional overhead to using C++ instead of C, but I still would suggest that you do not use new if you do not want thrown exceptions for out of memory. Malloc and calloc are much more fun anyway.

Comment: What does DES have to do with the question?